# Adverbs of frequency in passive voice present perfect constructions

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

With adverbs of frequency, we place the adverb *before* a main verb, *after* 'to be' and *between* auxiliary verbs and the main verb.

What happens when the sentence is in the present perfect passive voice, where the main verb is 'to be'?

> I **have been frequently** angered by his behaviour
>  OR
>  I **have
> frequently been** angered by his behaviour

Are both correct, or is one considered grammatically incorrect?

Comment: See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&content=have+frequently+been+used%2Chave+been+frequently+used%2Chave+been+used+frequently&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20frequently%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20frequently%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20used%20frequently%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20frequently%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20frequently%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20used%20frequently%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: ...showing that adverbial ***frequently*** can occur after the first OR second auxiliary verb *(**have, been**)* OR after the entire 3-word "verb element" ***have been angered***. It's really no different to similar adverbs such as ***often***.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to this unique way of researching usage.

Answer (score -1):

They are both usable in standard American dialect, but they mean slightly different things:

> been frequently angered

Here 'frequently' modified 'angered', and thus emphasizes the anger.

> frequently been angered

Here frequently modifies the state of 'being angered' and thus emphasizes the process a bit more.